# Chrome app with a background script running inside restricted scope

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

We have a web application that runs on both desktop and internet enabled TVs. Currently we're using the User-Agent header to determine which interface to serve.

I've now been tasked with making the TV interface accessible from desktop browsers without blocking access to the desktop website, so I figured wrapping it up as a chrome app would do the trick and it does, but with a few issues.

### Packaged App Method

I created a packaged app with a plain html file containing an iframe that loads the main website and some javascript using the chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders function to override the User-Agent.

manifest.json

```
{
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "local_path": "index.html"
        }
    },
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "cookies",
        "*://my.site.url/*"
    ]
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="http://my.site.url"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) 
    {
        var headers = details.requestHeaders;

        for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) 
        {
            if (headers[i].name === 'User-Agent') 
            {
                headers[i].value += " Chromebox"
                break;
    }
        }
        return {requestHeaders: headers};
    }, 
    {
        urls: ["*://my.site.url/*"]
    }, 
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

#### Issues

- I have to allow the entire site to be loaded
  inside an iframe, opening it up to possible clickjacking
- when the app is open it also triggers the onBeforeSendHeaders listener when navigating to the main site in another tab, causing the User-Agent to be modified and all requests to the site get redirected to the TV interface.

### Hosted App Method

I created a hosted app with the start url pointing to the main site and created a background page that runs the javascript to override the User-Agent.

manifest.json

```
{
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http://my.site.url"
        }
    },
    "background_page": "https://my.site.url/chromebox/index.html",
    "permissions": [
        "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "background",
        "*://my.site.url/*"
    ]
}
```

index.html

```
<html><script src="main.js"></script></html>
```

#### Issues

- Once installed the background page javascript is always running so users are always redirected to the TV site

The ideal solution would be a hosted app that has the background page only running when the app is open and the onBeforeSendHeaders listener does not affect any requests outside of the chrome app.

Does anybody have any idea of how I may achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I got your problem straight, but if I did, here's a `main.js` for your **Hosted App** method:

```
function parse_url(str,component){var key=['source','scheme','authority','userInfo','user','pass','host','port','relative','path','directory','file','query','fragment'],ini=(this.php_js&&this.php_js.ini)||{},mode=(ini['phpjs.parse_url.mode']&&ini['phpjs.parse_url.mode'].local_value)||'php',parser={php:/^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/()(?:(?:()(?:([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?()(?:(()(?:(?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)()(?:[^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/,strict:/^(?:([^:\/?#]+):)?(?:\/\/((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?))?((((?:[^?#\/]*\/)*)([^?#]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/,loose:/^(?:(?![^:@]+:[^:@\/]*@)([^:\/?#.]+):)?(?:\/\/\/?)?((?:(([^:@]*):?([^:@]*))?@)?([^:\/?#]*)(?::(\d*))?)(((\/(?:[^?#](?![^?#\/]*\.[^?#\/.]+(?:[?#]|$)))*\/?)?([^?#\/]*))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?)/};var m=parser[mode].exec(str),uri={},i=14;while(i--){if(m[i]){uri[key[i]]=m[i];}}
if(component){return uri[component.replace('PHP_URL_','').toLowerCase()];}
if(mode!=='php'){var name=(ini['phpjs.parse_url.queryKey']&&ini['phpjs.parse_url.queryKey'].local_value)||'queryKey';parser=/(?:^|&)([^&=]*)=?([^&]*)/g;uri[name]={};uri[key[12]].replace(parser,function($0,$1,$2){if($1){uri[name][$1]=$2;}});}
delete uri.source;return uri;}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){
    if(!details.requestHeaders) return details; // skip parsing if missing request headers
    var domain = parse_url(details.url,'host');
    if(host.indexOf('my.site.com')!==0) return details; // skip parsing if it doesn't go to your site
    host=host.split('/'); if(host[1] && host[1]!=='') return details; // skip parsing if it doesn't go to the index

    var headers = details.requestHeaders;
    for(var i in headers){
        if(!headers[i] || !headers[i].name || !headers[i].value) continue;
        if(headers[i].name!=='string') continue;
        if(headers[i].name.toLowerCase()!=='user-agent') continue;

        details.requestHeaders[i].value += ' Chromebox'
        break;
    }

    return details; //  OK BOSS
});
```

[`Parse_url()` function stolen from PHP.js](http://phpjs.org/functions/parse_url:485)